# Duplicating latest record in next months until there's a change

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to query ids and their type every month but I only have two tables of which one contains all ids and the other one contains type changes transactions. When I joined them, it gave me null values for months with no change.

```
SELECT a.month_date, a.id, b.type
FROM id_table a
LEFT JOIN type_changes_table b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.month_date = b.month_date
```

Is there a way using Presto SQL/amazon athena to duplicate the latest value to the next months until there is no change (ex. expected column in the picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `last_value(ignore nulls)`:

```
SELECT i.month_date, i.id, c.type,
       LAST_VALUE(c.type IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY i.id ORDER BY i.month_date) as imputed_type
FROM id_table i LEFT JOIN
     type_changes_table c
     ON i.id = c.id AND i.month_date = c.month_date;
```

Comment: For some reason, if I add ignore nulls, it results to an error. But if I don't put it, it doesn't return the expected output...